how to update apache atlas entity
I am trying to update my hive_table entity (table).
After get the entity guid, I sent the request for the partial Update, but i get this error
curl "http://xxxxxxxxxx:21000/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/5a71e80b-c610-4a0f-bb30-f196225114d6" \
-i -X PUT --negotiate \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-u username:password -d @entidad.json

{"errorCode":"ATLAS-400-00-023","errorMessage":"Attribute null not found for type hive_table"}[
please any suggestion??
